# Ocean modifier not showing waves

Tags: modifiers

I just created a plane and added the ocean modifier, but it isn't showing the waves. What am I doing wrong? I am following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CwJrb3vjAaA
[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot in Edit Mode? I think the problem has to do with the amount of vertices.

Answer (score 2):

Set this to generate

[image]

... there u go ;)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't enough geometry for displacement (only 1 face).
Set Geometry to *Generate* and it will create new faces based on the *Resolution* value.

(or you can keep it set to Displace, but add a *Subdivision modifier* with 6-7 levels)

[image]